# Need help in generating a CFG for a language

Tags: string, match, grammar, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I want to match strings that contain "k" number of 0's followed by "k+4" number of 1's where k is greater than or equal to zero

I tried the following grammar is this correct?

```
S->0S1|1111
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. Though one would say that the grammar *generates* the strings, not *match*.